# Value shows nan instead of NaN

Tags: python, null, nan

[image]

Hi guys, because the old price column is nan not NaN. the df.isnull().sum() cant work on it.
The value counts read it as another value as well.
In the excel files, it is totally blank.

Anyone experience this before? Could i have some help please?

Comment: `df['old_price'].replace('nan',np.nan)`

Comment: Could you share how do you import the dataframe and a few lines of your excel?